# Change all merge tags of a list in MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using the API v3 of MailChimp to send emails. I have around 10.000 subscribers in my list, and I want to change all MERGE TAGS. The way I'm doing it right now is, getting the List ID. Get all the emails of that list, and go one by one updating the field.

It takes 2 hours to change them all. Is there a way to update all of them?

I'm updating them right now this way:
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#

Comment: For this, does change all merge tags mean you're updating all data in each subscribers profile fields? And is it required or do you prefer that this is done through their API?

Comment: Yes I mean change all the data in each profile field. The data will be the same. And yes, I have to use the API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably is too late for this answer but,

Mailchimp API V3.0 use batch operations now

You could save different operations of this type in an array

```
operation = {
   method : 'put',
   path : '/lists/'+list.id+"/members/"+hashEmail,
   body : {
       FNAME: "Jhonny", 
       LNAME: "Bravo" , 
   }
}

batchOperations.push(operation);

operation = {
   method : 'patch',
   path : '/lists/'+list.id+"merge-fields/" + merge_id
   body : {
          tag : field.tag,
          name : field.name,
          type : "text",
          public : false,
          default_value : ""
   }
}
batchOperations.push(operation);
```

and send a POST request to /3.0/batches

```
 request = {
    method : 'post',
    path : '/3.0/batches',
    body : {
       operations : batchOperations  
    }
 }
```

More info about Mailchimp's batch operations here http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-batch-operations/